# bing maps showing large (grid)lines

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I wanted to integrate Bing Maps in a website from one of our clients. Unfortunately I get strange results. Unfortunately I can't add an image. There are these large (grid?) lines (up to some 10 pixels wide), but I do not know how to remove them. I use the following basic code:

```
var map = null;
            function getMap() {
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    credentials: '...mycredentials....'
                    ,enableClickableLogo: false
                    ,enableSearchLogo: false
                    ,showDashboard: false
                    ,zoom: 14
                    ,center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(...thelatitude...,...thelongitude...)
                });
                map.entities.clear(); 
                var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null); 
                map.entities.push(pushpin);
            }
            getMap();
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't have CSS that mess with Bing Maps tile (after all, it's all about images or div..). Also check if you got similar issues in various browser. Let us know

Comment: As Nicolas mentions, it's likely you have CSS in your app that is causing this. Also make sure you have the UTF-8 metatag: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Thanks Nicolas and rBrundritt. That was the problem. It was CSS. I had default padding on images and the tiles in the Bing Map are also images. Thanks for your input!

Comment: The issue was local to the user and sorted out in the comments.